# Trigger DAG in Google Cloud Conductor with Parameter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, airflow

In the https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf example, it allows you to trigger a dag by name based on an event.  Could you also pass an argument to the dag from the event, such as the filename that was added to the bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was indeed able to trigger a DAG from Cloud Functions with parameters.
For this, I used the [Rest API Plugin made by robertsanders](https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-rest-api-plugin/blob/master/plugins/rest_api_plugin.py)

I had to pass a JSON map as a parameter to the WEBSERVER_URL :

```
const WEBSERVER_URL = 'https://' + WEBSERVER_ID + '.appspot.com/admin/rest_api/api?api=trigger_dag&dag_id=' + DAG_NAME + '&conf=%7B%22fileName%22%3A%22' + fileName + '%22%7D';
```

Then, in a PythonOperator, I was able to get the fileName entry of the map like this :

```
def get_file_name_from_trigger(ds, **kwargs):
    return kwargs['dag_run'].conf['fileName']
```